# Can I transfer 3DS stuff from one SD card to another?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have a 3ds with the stock 2gb SD in it. I want to download full retail titles, but not many are going to fit on that card before it gets filled up.

My plan is to eventually get a bigger SD card, but I want to keep the stuff that is on my original SD card and put it on the new one, so I don't have to worry about swapping SD cards.

Is there a way to do that? Or are things essentially locked on the SD card once they are put on there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

On the SD card is a folder named "Nintendo 3DS" Simply copy this folder to your new SD card, and everything will come along with it. When you place your new SD card into your system, it may take a bit of extra time to start up (mine did) but I believe it is just reading in the new card and making sure everything matches up.

Comment: Could you also do this with a computer? For example, put your SD card into a computer, copy all the files from your 3DS's SD card into a folder in the computer, use the SD card for something else, and then when you want to use the SD card again for your games, move the files you have on your SD and transfer the old files you had on your SD card back from the computer?

Comment: @Animal-Crosser ~ Yes, that works.